# menu with section title and description in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I need to create a menu with a list of sections AND their descriptions. How can I do that in Joomla?

the desired layout is something like:

> Video
>
> *Only the newest TV series!*
>
> Music
>
> *Browse our latest artists!*

..etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension like mod_categories as a basis to make a module that will show section/category titles plus their descriptions. I've done modicifations like that myself and it is not difficult.